# Verifying multiple text sub-strings in numerous cells

Tags: text, compare, substring, cells

First time poster and new to VB but fairly fluent in Excel.
I have a question similar to what's asked in this post ([excel: how can I identify rows containing text keywords taken from a list of keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395971/excel-how-can-i-identify-rows-containing-text-keywords-taken-from-a-list-of-key)) however I need to read strings of text in both columns and compare them. If I find 2 or more matching strings I want the value from my second column to be used for my output in my 3rd column.

So in column A I have:
7-zip beta
Adobe Acrobat
ActivePerl
Apache Tomcat 7.9.0
Excel Chart Utilities
Microsoft Office Ultimate 2007

In column B I have:
7zip
Adobe Acrobat Reader
Apache Tomcat 
Excel Chart

In column C I want the official software entry from column B if 2 or more text sub-string match.

Problems: my column A still contains the version number for the software I want to compare and is not necessary entered into my spreadsheet the same way as my official software list should be (column B). My column B contains only 600 rows while my column A contains close to 8000 rows. In addition, all duplicates in the respective columns have already been removed.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try following VBA - quite general solution - it might help, eventually adapted to your exact needs:

```
Private Sub Test()
Dim a As Range, b As Range, cel As Range, match As Boolean
Set a = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A") ' can be set eventually upgraded to reflect only non-blank cells
Set b = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B") ' same as above and you can eliminage the Exit Sub statement 

For Each cel In b.Cells
If cel.Value = "" Then Exit Sub ' this can be eliminated
match = False
    match = InStr(1, UCase(cel.Offset(0, -1).Value), UCase(cel.Value), vbTextCompare) > 0
    If match = True Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel.Value
    Else
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel.Offset(0, -1).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```