# Excel: Search rows for keywords and populate cells with those keywords

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This question will be almost exactly like the question below, but I need a slight change to it for my application and I can't quite figure it out:

[excel: how can I identify rows containing text keywords taken from a list of keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395971/excel-how-can-i-identify-rows-containing-text-keywords-taken-from-a-list-of-key/12396430#12396430)

If a row of several text filled cells contains any keyword from a list of keywords, I would like to add that keyword to the end of the row. Each row will be the same number of cells, but some can be blank and they are not necessarily all the same data type, some could be numbers or dates etc. Even more, I would like to add every keyword that appears in the row of text to the end of the row in separate cells.

Relating to the example post that almost answers my question, I am using the more complicated formula for multiple matches, but in that example they only have one column of data they are looking for keywords in. I have several that would be formatted similar to their column A. I tried changing some of the ranges around with no luck specifically where the formula posted has: `IF(COUNTIF($A1,"*"&$B$1:$B$10&"*")` I changed $A1, to $A1:$D1 with no luck.

The problem showed up because I have several large spreadsheets of text based data about failure modes of different tools and I would like to categorize them in a little more of a controlled way than free form text in every cell and assigning controlled keywords that apply seems like a decent way to do this.

[Example case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXjtX.jpg)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gudfZ.jpg)

The keyword list shown in Example Case is not shown in the Expected result. The range of keywords is K2:K6

Another feature that would be useful is if I could assign additional words that when found would trigger one of the key words. For example if the key word is "Gear wear" then "Gear wear" would trigger a hit but "stripped gears" would also trigger a hit. I would imagine the keyword list would be set up as a 2D Range with the first column being the actual key word and the cells to the right of each row would be additional words that trigger the key word. I suspect I am getting to the point where I would need to create a VBA macro to do this. If there is a way to accomplish this without writing code it would make it more repeatable on other user's computers.

Answer (score 0):

Enter following formula in `Cell F1` then drag/copy across and down as required.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($K$2:$K$6,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A1:$D1,"*"&$K$2:$K$6&"*"),ROW($K$2:$K$6)-ROW($A$1)),COLUMNS($A1:A1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

See the image for reference

[image]

This formula is derived from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395971/excel-how-can-i-identify-rows-containing-text-keywords-taken-from-a-list-of-key/12396430#12396430) mentioned in your question.

Comment: @QuinnBlankenheim - Did this help?